# CodeMirror editor autocompletion for predefined words

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

I have website where I user CodeMirror editor to enter data. I want to add very simple autocomplete feature: I have some words started with @ symbol (@cat, @dog, @bird etc) and I want editor to show dropdown with this words when user types @ or @c - how can I do this? I see autocomplete plugins but they need to press ctrl+space and works with schemas... so, any help will be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here's how (assuming you've loaded CodeMirror and the `show-hint` addon):

```
// Dummy mode that puts words into their own token
// (You probably have a mode already)
CodeMirror.defineMode("mylanguage", function() {
  return {token: function(stream, state) {
    if (stream.match(/[@\w+]/)) return "variable";
    stream.next();
    return null;
  }};
});
// Register an array of completion words for this mode
CodeMirror.registerHelper("hintWords", "mylanguage",
                          ["@cat", "@dog", "@bird"]);

// Create an editor
var editor = CodeMirror(document.body, {mode: "mylanguage"});
// When an @ is typed, activate completion
editor.on("inputRead", function(editor, change) {
  if (change.text[0] == "@")
    editor.showHint();
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for help! I added 'show-hint' addon, and added new helper like you suggest. Can you please help me to understand how this should work? :) I think I'm on right way, just want to get this working))

Comment: The problem was more with my example code than with your interpretation of it. I hadn't properly read your question and my code contained a bug. I've fixed and expanded it a bit. Note that the first argument to `registerHelper` has to correspond to your language mode name, and that your mode has to at least put such @foo constructs into their own token for the autocompletion to work.

Comment: How to merge this with javascript mode, because I want js-syntax highlight's stay.